# I have never seen either + sentence or + sentence

Tags: possessives, case

Is it grammatically correct to add a full sentence after the word *either* and the word *or*  as in the following sentence, or should it be written as in the second sentence?

> 1. My brother is a cook and works in a pizza restaurant. However, I have
>      never seen either ***he is cooking a meal*** or ***( making) a pizza*** at home.
> 2. My brother is a cook and works in a pizza restaurant. However, I have
>      never seen either ***his cooking  a meal*** or  ***(making) a pizza*** at home.

Comment: Take out *either*. What do you think about *I have never seen  he is cooking a meal at home*??

Comment: I would say _"I have never seen him either cooking a meal or (making) a pizza at home"_

Comment: Don't be distracted by the *either X or Y* construction. The basic syntactic constraints on what ***X*** can be are exactly the same in *I have never seen X*. That's to say, ***X*** should be a *noun* (some *thing* which could in principle be the object of ***to see***). But a complete SVO statement such as ***He is cooking*** isn't a noun. The only valid way to use it after ***see*** would be something like ***I can see** [that] **he is cooking***, where the assertion is effectively *I can see **that X is a true statement***.

Comment: @AlanCarmack A pizza is not a meal so I wanted to mention separately.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see so is it correct to say  "My brother is a cook and works in a pizza restaurant. However, I have never seen either that he is cooking a meal or (that ) ( making) a pizza at home."

Comment: @Mrt You're missing the point Alan is making. Reread the simplified sentence. Does it look correct to you ?

Comment: @Irhala it doesn't sound bad . do you mean it should have been written "I have never seen that he is cooking a meal at home"

Comment: @Mrt This doesn't have the same meaning : it means _he's cooking at home but you've never seen him do so_. The former sentence felt like _he never cooks home_.

Comment: @Mrt: No - it's very unlikely any native speaker would ever say *I have never seen [that] he is cooking a meal*. Forget about the negation as well as the *either/or* business, and simplify the Present Perfect into Simple Past - that would leave you with *I saw [that] he is cooking*, which hopefully you can see doesn't make a lot of sense (almost certainly what the speaker *means* there is *I saw that he **was** cooking*).

Comment: @Irhala I get this sense now but did not inferred at first. So your suggesting sentence means  "he never cooks" , which I want to mean, while Mr.Carmack's sentence means " I have never seen , even if he cooks at home"

Comment: '+I have never seen he is cooking a meal at home' is ungrammatical in standard English for the reason fumblefingers mentions. The transitive use of the verb *see* requires a noun phrase, and 'he is cooking at home' is not a noun phrase. Using the *either/or* construction doesn't change that. So you would need  to use the gerund/-ing forms, because they are noun phrases.

Comment: Then I should say " I have never seen him cooking " or "I have never seen him when he either cooks  a meal or makes a pizza"  or  "I have never seen him when he is either cooking  a meal or making a pizza."

Comment: You have been a member here for long enough to know how to ask a question. Please quote the source of the sentence and include your own research.

Comment: I have never seem him cook a meal or make a pizza at home.

Answer (score 1):

1 is wrong. #2 would be better stated "My brother is a cook in a pizza restaurant. However, I have never seen him either prepare a meal or make a pizza at home."